# The fluid in my scene is not simulating

Tags: fluid-simulation

I am making a fountain and I would like the water to flow from a gap in the chest of a statue to create the illusion of blood flowing from a wound. However, the fluid simulation is not working. I have appended the blend file and I hope that someone will be so kind as to take a look at it. 
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: File not appended or available.

Comment: it should be there. Are you sure you can't locate the file?